# Finding the positions of minima for a function with algebraic constants

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, conditional

I have a function of several variables:

```
 inverse[Qx_, Qy_]:= T - 2 J + 4 J1 Cos[(Qx + Qy)/2 a] Cos[(Qx - Qy)/2 a] - 2 J2 Cos[(Qx - Qy) a] + 2 J3 Cos[(Qx + Qy) a]
```

and wanted to find its minima with Qx and Qy being the variables and setting the others, i.e., T, J, J1, J2, J3, being constants. The minima would probably be determined by the conditions on the constants and so I would also like the answers to give those conditions. The only condition I have at the start is that all of the constants should be positive.

I've now tried this Minimize function but it doesn't seem to print anything in particular:

```
 Minimize[{inverse[Qx, Qy], T >= 0 && J >= 0 && J1 >= 0 && J2 >= 0 && J3 >= 0}, {Qx, Qy}]
```

Comment: To start, note that `/.{T>=0,J>=0,J1>=0,J2>=0,J3>=0}` is not correct usage. `/.` carries out explicit replacements, and uses rules (e.g. `expression /. T -> 0`). You would want to look into `Minimize` and its syntax.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for that, I've edited the question and will have a look now for that function.

Comment: `Inverse` cannot be used for your own definitions. In general it's a good idea to have your own definitions start with a small letter.